# Did Chomsky originate the term "rewrite rule"?

Tags: terminology, phrase-structure, chomsky

The earliest mention of the term "rewrite rule" that I am able to find - in the context of phrase structure grammars - is in Chomsky's "Syntactic Structures" (1957).

Did he originate the term?

Comment: I think Zellig Harris was the one who first employed the term in linguistics (Chomsky studied under Harris). Harris seems to have gotten the idea (and perhaps the term) from various logicians (incl Emil Post) who may have been using it as early as 1914.

Comment: Pretty sure Post is the first to formalize these and use the term "string rewriting system" (or something close to it).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system

Comment: @Fred Yes, either Post or Axel Thue.

Comment: I looked for an answer but couldn't find one.  The question, I take it, is about the specific term, not the idea or the system that uses rewrite rules.

Comment: Post did not use the term "rule" in his publications. Thue (who was the one who wrote in 1914) didn't use English; Harris did not use the term in the publications which preceded Syntactic Structures that I looked at (not a complete search); Chomsky did not use it in his dissertation (did not check LSLT since I don't have a PDF of that).

Comment: @GregLee yes, I am referring to the specific term.

Comment: For what it's worth, Chomsky takes credit for the terms in “Explanatory Models in Linguistics” (1960): "...each of these components consists of two fundamentally different parts, a set of what I shall call 'rewriting rules' and a set of 'transformational rules.'"